# R custom package - Imported function not found when trying to create NAMESPACE

Tags: r, package, r-s4, roxygen2

I'm working on a custom R package, in which I'm using S4 classes and methods.
In one of the methods for a custom S4 class in the same file, I'm using the `GET()` method from the `httr` package. I tried using roxygen2 to properly set up my NAMESPACE file, having put `@importFrom httr GET` in the roxygen2 comment of the method and importing the package in the DESCRIPTION file.

```
#' 
#' @importFrom httr GET
setMethod(f="method_name",
          signature="Class_name",
          definition=function()
          {
            ...
            foo<- GET(url = "bar")
            ...
          }
```

However, when executing `devtools::document()`, I'm getting:
 `Error in method_name() (from file_name.R#198) : could not find function "GET"`

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:
It seems roxygen2 never properly generates a NAMESPACE file. I deleted the old (outdated) one, but `devtools::document()` won't create a new one.

Comment: What do the relevant parts of your DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE look like after `devtools::document()`? (perhaps include them in your question).

Comment: They actually seem to remain unchanged. There are some imports and exports from a past 'devtools::document()' call, but none of the new imports/exports seems to be recongnized/put into the NAMESPACE file. Maybe I missed some requirements for roxygen2 to properly work.

Comment: Did you `#' @export` the functions?

Comment: Not this one in particular. But my understanding was, that you only `@export`functions you want to be publicly available in your package? The method in question is only internally used (it is the overwritten `initialize` method of one of the S4 classes).